# Excel ExportOptions vb.net 2 crystal reports 8.5 - no effect

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to export an excel file with CRAXDRT.dll

Heres the Code:

Dim frmFormat As New frmFormatOptions
                frmFormat.ShowDialog()

```
            If frmFormat.okPressed Then
                If frmFormat.excelVersion = 7 Then
                    report.ExportOptions.FormatType = CRExportFormatType.crEFTExcel70
                ElseIf frmFormat.excelVersion = 8 Then
                    report.ExportOptions.FormatType = CRExportFormatType.crEFTExcel80
                End If

                report.ExportOptions.ExcelUseConstantColumnWidth = frmFormat.constantColumnWidth

                If frmFormat.constantColumnWidth Then
                    report.ExportOptions.ExcelConstantColumnWidth = frmFormat.columnWidth
                End If
                report.ExportOptions.ExcelUseTabularFormat = frmFormat.useTabular
                report.ExportOptions.ExcelUseWorksheetFunctions = frmFormat.worksheetFunctions
                report.ExportOptions.ExcelTabHasColumnHeadings = frmFormat.columnHeadings






            Else
                report.ExportOptions.FormatType = CRExportFormatType.crEFTExcel80
            End If

            report.ExportOptions.DestinationType = CRExportDestinationType.crEDTDiskFile
            report.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = rptxls

            'report.ExportOptions..PDFExportAllPages = True
            report.Export(False)
```

But whatever the form returns, the formatoptions wont take effect.
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It worked with

```
report.ExportOptions.FormatType = CRExportFormatType.crEFTExcel80Tabular
```